# Replace part of end of string with equal number of given characters

Tags: javascript

Given the string `abc11111` and `232`.
Is there an elegant way to replace the last 3 "in this case" characters so that the results would be `abc11232`?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript **[`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method

```js
var str1 = 'abc11111',
  str2 = '232';

console.log(
  str1.slice(0, -str2.length) + str2
);
```

---

Or use **[`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** or **[`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** method.

```js
var str1 = 'abc11111',
  str2 = '232';

console.log(
  str1.substring(0, str1.length - str2.length) + str2
);

// or

console.log(
  str1.substr(0, str1.length - str2.length) + str2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `RegExp` constructor(accepts dynamic replacing string length) and `String.replace` function:

```js
var str1 = 'abc11111', str2 = '232', 
    re = new RegExp(".{"+ str2.length +"}$");

console.log(str1.replace(re, str2));
```